# Why does Project Facet window not open in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have generated an app engine backend in eclipse for an existing Android app. I wanted to configure the project to use Cloud SQL by following this link https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools

When I do: right click on project -->Properties -->Project Facet --> selected JPA v2.0 and click Further configuration available option eclipse just gets stuck for ages and nothing happens?

What should I do? Also is there a way of using Endpoints with cloudsql without using JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing the lastest version of eclipse Juno v4.2